# ebean query for not matching more than 1 objects

Tags: sql, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I want to have a query that gives me a list of objects that do not hold a rule (for example id!=10)
for that, I can write something like this :

```
new Finder<>(Long.class, Device.class).where().ne("id", 10l).findList();
```

now I want to say, give a list where id!=10 && id!=20 && ...
to achieve this, 1 way is to use multiple `.ne`, but I do not know how long my list could be,

Is there any way to  achieve this?

I use Ebean that is shipped with Play framework 2.3.4

thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following methods:

```
/**
* Not In - property has a value in the array of values.
*/
ExpressionList<T> notIn(String propertyName, Object... values);

/**
* Not In - property has a value in the collection of values.
*/
ExpressionList<T> notIn(String propertyName, Collection<?> values);

Ebean.find(Device.class).where().notIn("id", myArrayOfIds).findList();

Ebean.find(Device.class).where().notIn("id", myListOfIds).findList();
```